# Is there a service converting web application into native iOs+Android apps AND supporting pusher.com

Tags: push-notification, pusher

There is a mess of services converting your existing web application into a native iOS and/or Android app.
For push notifications they all support OneSignal.
But I couldn't find any supporting Pusher.com.

**Did anybody know a service like GoNative which support Pusher?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While I am not familiar with app conversion tools you mentioned, you should be able to use Pusher Beams SDKs for Android and iOS directly.

You can find the SDKs here:

- iOS: https://github.com/pusher/push-notifications-swif
- Android: https://github.com/pusher/push-notifications-android

And there are several tutorials published on Pusher Tutorials site, just search for the `Beams` tag:

https://pusher.com/tutorials?tag=Beams

Comment: But this means that we need to do the app conversion on our own. We currently have not the resources and not the experience for that. Gonative could do this but they just support OneSignal. We prefer to use pusher.